# Api Google Maps - highlight roads in a radius of kilometers (not a circle around a point)

Tags: maps

How can i highlight roads within a radius of miles from a specific point? (not a circle around the point)

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge you will have to use the polyline xml features within the Google Maps API.

Here is an example that highlights the CA I5 using polylines. http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GenericMapBrowser.asp?filename=I5Polyline.xml

I don't know the exact implementation to restrict the road radius from a point, but if google does not offer a simple solution within the API, you may want to look into the haversine formula for dealing with radii and geographic co-ordinates.

Comment: wow .. haversine formula is astrogoto  for me;)
the script you've been through is very interesting, I'm trying to find a way to use it for my purposes, but unfortunately I have not managed to find an algorithm that will allow me to do what I need ....
Thinking about ... maybe if I could extract all addresses that  are part of a range I could use your script to highlight it... but I do not know how to extract them...